# Error when I try to start any simulation on Cooja/Contiki

Tags: msp430, contiki

I'm trying to start my first simulator on Cooja/Contiki, but I'm getting the below error:

```
> make hello-world.sky TARGET=sky 
CC        hello-world.c
CC        ../../platform/sky/./contiki-sky-main.c
LD        hello-world.sky
/usr/lib64/gcc/msp430/4.6.4/../../../../msp430/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib64/gcc/msp430/4.6.4/mmpy-16/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib64/gcc/msp430/4.6.4/../../../../msp430/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib64/gcc/msp430/4.6.4/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib64/gcc/msp430/4.6.4/../../../../msp430/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/lib64/gcc/msp430/4.6.4/../../../../msp430/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib64/gcc/msp430/4.6.4/mmpy-16/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib64/gcc/msp430/4.6.4/../../../../msp430/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib64/gcc/msp430/4.6.4/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib64/gcc/msp430/4.6.4/../../../../msp430/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/lib64/gcc/msp430/4.6.4/../../../../msp430/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib64/gcc/msp430/4.6.4/mmpy-16/libcrt0.a when searching for -lcrt0
/usr/lib64/gcc/msp430/4.6.4/../../../../msp430/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib64/gcc/msp430/4.6.4/libcrt0.a when searching for -lcrt0
/usr/lib64/gcc/msp430/4.6.4/../../../../msp430/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrt0
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
../../Makefile.include:280: recipe for target 'hello-world.sky' failed
rm hello-world.co obj_sky/contiki-sky-main.o
make: *** [hello-world.sky] Error 1
Process returned error code 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Could your problem be connected to this thread: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1175942 ?

If it does, I solved it from Fedora 23 by installing Fedora 20 version of MSP430 toolchain:

```
dnf install --releasever=20 msp430-gcc msp430-libc msp430mcu msp430-binutils
```

Hope it helps,
LS